# How to enter bios in legacy mode with fastboot disabled

Tags: uefi, bios

I need to change a few settings from bios. If I can just disable fast boot then I will be able to go to the bios. I need to change these settings - legacy mode to uefi mode. I am using ideapad slim 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried pressing F12 or the Novo Button to enter the BIOS when the computer is booting?

Comment: i have tried the novo button but no luck, and i have tried f2 but not f12, i will try f12

Comment: I tried spamming f2 and f12 but it didnt work, it just gets stuck on the lenovo logo

Comment: Most boxes have a key that will enter BIOS/uEFI setup mode; but it's firmware specific.  I have boxes that use F2, F9, F12, thinkVantage, Blue-button, & others keys, even a Black button that needs to be held for 3 secs with box off for setup mode to activate (box turns on with key held) - ie. it's firmware specific.  Given I have trouble remembering all keys... if I don't get it in 3-4 attempts; I just install recent Ubuntu *live* media & an option appears in the settings that allows me to enter setup without any machine/firmware specific knowledge.

Comment: so how do i know which "firmware" i have?

Comment: The firmware you'll note on bootup; as it's placed on your machine during manufacture (ie. it's on a chip on the motherboard being device specific).  Usually it's identical for all variations of *ideapad slim 3* device you state it is, however if the model is popular & is manufactured for >6 months it's possible it's changed, esp. if device is veru popular enough (ie. sells very well) that it's made for >12 months.  ie. it's not software directly, but software written on chip prior to manufacturer; your product seller will have best details if you can't see details *flash* at boot

Comment: Most systems use a normal boot from full "cold" shutdown. Then you have time to press the correct key to get into UEFI. Check manual so you are using correct key as it varies by vendor. If tablet it may have a reset pin hole to reset system.

Comment: Some Lenovo models have the usual FN keys and their secondary functions (multimedia keys, etc.) inverted. So, in those models, you'd use FN+F2.